# Products not showing in Google Shopping tabs despite having Merchant Center account set up

Tags: google-merchant-center

I have set up a Google Merchant Center account and created a product feed to try to get my items to appear in search results and Google Shopping tabs. However, after several days, none of my products are visible.

I have followed all the recommended steps:

```
Enabled the Free Listings program in Merchant Center
Set up a valid feed of all my products with multiple attributes
Verified that the data complies with Google's quality policies
I have not violated any Google Shopping policies
```

Despite this, I do not see my products when searching related terms on Google, nor in the Shopping tab.

Additionally, I have not created any paid shopping campaigns, so I fully depend on free listings for now.

I have checked the Merchant Center dashboard and it shows no errors, but there are still no impressions or clicks.

What could be failing? Is there any other step or configuration I'm missing to get my products to appear in Google Shopping? How can I solve this problem?

Any help or suggestions is appreciated.